# How to write a sql query from these tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

First of all, I'm no SQL developer. Therefore, I needed help with retrieving some information from the three tables below.

I want to get the `names`, `order date` and the `product code` for those who have made an order for product with `product code` = 401.1201

How do i write the SQL query to retrieve the information from the tables?

**dbo.tblMaterial**

- MaterialId(PK, int, not null)
- CanBeOrdered(bit, not null)
- Name(nvarchar(200), not null)
- Price(decimal(18,2), not null)
- ProductCode(nvarchar(50), not null)

**dbo.tblMaterialOrder**

- MaterialOrderId(PK, int, not null)
- MembershipUserId(uniqueidentifyer, not null)
- FirstName(nvarchar(50), not null)
- LastName(nvarchar(100), not null)
- OrderDate(datetime, not null)

**dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem**

- MaterialOrderItemId(PK, int, not null)
- MembershipUserId(uniqueidentifyer, not null)
- ItemsCount(int, not null)
- ItemPrice(int, not null)
- MaterialOrder_MaterialOrderId(FK, int, not null)
- Material_MaterialId(FK, int, not null)

I have tried...

```
Select * From dbo.tblMaterialOrder mo Where Exists (Select MembershipUserId From
dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem Where dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem.Material_MaterialId = 
(Select MaterialId From dbo.tblMaterial Where (ProductCode = '401.1201')))
```

and

```
Select * from dbo.tblMaterialOrder, dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem, dbo.tblMaterial 
Where 
dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem.Material_MaterialId = '248' And 
dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem.MaterialOrder_MaterialOrderId = 
dbo.tblMaterialOrder.MaterialOrderId
```

with no success.

Comment: Is this school work? Have you made an attempt to write the SQL that you can share with us so we can point you in the right direction?

Comment: I have tryed a lot, this is my best try:

Comment: Select * From dbo.tblMaterialOrder mo
Where Exists (Select MembershipUserId From dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem Where dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem.Material_MaterialId = (Select MaterialId From dbo.tblMaterial Where (ProductCode = '401.1201')))

Comment: This is another try that doesnt work: Select * from dbo.tblMaterialOrder, dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem, dbo.tblMaterial
Where dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem.Material_MaterialId = '248' And dbo.tblMaterialOrderItem.MaterialOrder_MaterialOrderId = dbo.tblMaterialOrder.MaterialOrderId

Comment: From your attempts it looks as though you could do with reading about [JOINs in SQL](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp) which are fundamental to make sense of data stored in database tables where relationships exist between tables.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    tblMaterial.Name,
    tblMaterialOrder.OrderDate,
    tblMaterial.ProductCode
FROM
    tblMaterial
    JOIN tblMaterialOrderItem
        ON tblMaterial.MaterialId=tblMaterialOrderItem.Material_MaterialId
    JOIN tblMaterialOrder
        ON tblMaterialOrder.MaterialOrderId=tblMaterialOrderItem.MaterialOrder_MaterialOrderId
WHERE
    tblMaterial.ProductCode='401.1201'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  M.NAME
 ,M.MATERIALID
 ,O.ORDERDATE
FROM MATERIAL M
LEFT JOIN ORDERITEM OI ON M.MATERIALID = OI.MATERIAL_MATERIALID
LEFT JOIN ORDER O ON OI.MaterialOrder_MaterialOrderId = O.MaterialOrderId
WHERE M.MATERIALID = '401.1201'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested Skript:

```
select a.name, b.orderdate, a.productcode 
from tblMaterial a left outer join tblMaterialOrderItem b 
on a.MaterialId = b.Material_MaterialId 
left outer join tblMaterialOrder c 
on c.MaterialOrder_MaterialOrderId = b.MaterialOrderId
where a.productcode = '401.1201'
```